# How should I check if user is correct?

Tags: android, hash, fingerprint

I started to writing my first Android App.

I've tried to create a simple system which will allow user to get info, if he will authenticate with fingerprint.

I wrote fingerprint auth system to get confirmation if user is registered in the phone, but my question is: Is there any option to get "hash" of the fingerprint and store it for ex. in database to check if user should have access to the app?

---

I mean:

Database key: 123123123123ASDASDASDASD

Fingerprint key: 123123123123ASDASDASDASD

User has access to the app.

---

If read fingerprint key not equals stored in database, user doesn't have access to the app.

Is this even possile? - is there any other option to create system like above?

Answer (score 0):

By DB, are you talking a local DB or a remote one?  If remote-  that's a horrible and insecure idea.  You should never use a fingerprint to authorize someone on a remote device-  all I need to do is get a copy of someone's fingerprint, pretend its mine, and send it as the hash to gain access.  Fingerprint capture and authentication needs to be done on the same device.
If local its still a bad idea.  All the functionality you need is built into the fingerprint and account APIs.  Use them.  Don't store people's private biodata in unsecured storage (a db is unsecured storage).

Comment: Fingerprint would be hashed first before store - but, how can I know that register user is user that printed his finger? How to equal it with row in database?

Comment: @Freaky_ Which makes no difference to anything I said.

Comment: So how may I know that user who's printed his finger is in database? - should I store any accID, which would be accessible with login and password (which I wanted to avoid)? Somehow user must create the account, and somehow I must know that he is he -- The fingerprint would only tell me that it is phone owner, no one else - but what if someone break the login and password and just print his finger?

Comment: Ideally you don't use just fingerprints for anything.  You log in with username and password, and use fingerprints as a second factor for 2 factor authentication.  Fingerprints are actually a horrible single factor authentication mechanism.  Is your app local, or is it logging into a server?  If its local, you can get away with it.  If its client server, there is no way to do it securely with just a fingerprint form an uncontrolled remote device.

Comment: The exception is if you control both devices and the network between them-  for example an offline only fingerprint scanner on a bank vault.  But those are secure only because you've eliminated the possibility of an attack by faking the scan result (it can only come from tightly controlled physical access to a single device).

Comment: I mean, can I make an account using only fingerprint "hash" which can be compared between app and database? - to authenticate user basing on it at first, then on login+pass.